# What \usetheme or \usecolortheme?

Tags: beamer

I am working on my class presentation project using Latex Beamer. For template I would like to use one similar to this [*presentation*](http://www.cs.uu.nl/docs/vakken/ga/slides7.pdf) I found from the internet.

(1) Do you know what \usetheme or \usecolortheme did the author use? 
(2) Is there anyway to change the font to Garamond?

Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: I'd recommend that you just email the author of that beamer slide set and ask.   Or you can go here and select one that you like. http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/index.html  Or all at once https://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/ Or here for some nice fully set up theme/color in overleaf https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/presentation

Comment: Good idea to ask him. Thanks also for the links.

Comment: This looks like the `warsow` theme, with a reddish `structure` beamercolor.

Comment: Apology for seeing you late, but here is my "thanks!" for giving me clue.

Answer (score 3):

You can find here the combination of themes and colors
https://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/

To change the font just put this on your preamble

```
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Apologize for seeing you late, but here are my many, many thsnks.

Comment: If this answer fits you needs, accept it please, instead of saying `Thank you` only